# how to make Authentication in Gatsby paired with WordPress as a headless CMS?

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, wordpress-rest-api, headless-cms

I am working o a project where I am using Gatsby for front-End and WordPress as a headless CMS for the back end but now I want to add user registration, authentication and a client area which will only be available to authenticated users but I am lost as to how to implement this functionality

I can fetch data from WordPress but I don't know how to send and then process that data in WordPress,
any ideas or guidelines will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar setup on a project, just with Next.js.

We use Firebase for the authentication process and have the whole setup with user profile, notifications, etc.

[Here](https://betterprogramming.pub/build-a-gatsby-authentication-flow-with-firebase-72b9514f6c9b?gi=e3d10923567d) is a how-to for integration Firebase Authentication into Gatsby